# Python3 проблема с потоком

Tags: python-3.x, многопоточность

Возникла проблема с выполнением потока в классе:

```
class SourceCode:
    @staticmethod
    def _get_driver() -> webdriver:
        options = ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        return webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

    def __init__(self, kind=None):
        options = ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        self.kinds = ['some','kinds','of','something']
        self.__counter = 1
        self.kind = kind
        self.total_count = 0
        Thread(target=self.get_total_count).start()

    def get_total_count(self):
        driver = self._get_driver()
        for kind in self.kinds:
            driver.get('XXX' + kind)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
            _ = soup.find('span', {'class': 'something'}).text
            _ = sub('[А-Яа-я]+', '', _)
            self.total_count += int(_.strip())
```

При создании отдельного потока в конструкторе класса - происходят странные вещи. Я получаю не ти числа, которые обычно получал при синхронной работе. Причем они всегда разные.
Если при синхронной работе я получаю `46000`, то при работе метода в потоке я получаю то `38`, то `12000` и.т.д.

Ощущение, что это какая-то базовая трабла с потоками, о которой я не знаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А как вы вообще узнаёте, что поток завершился? Вы же это никак не проверяете и не можете проверить, поскольку запускаете поток "в свободное плавание". Вам нужно как-то убедиться, что поток завершился, иначе я подозреваю вы получаете промежуточный результат работы функции.
Для этого нужно либо сохранить поток в переменную и сделать потом `thread.join()`, либо лучше использовать какую-то асинхронную библиотеку.

Comment: этот  поток кстати может gc сожрать в любой момент)

Comment: @eri Кстати, да ))

Comment: это основная проблема, join не обязателен в этой программе

Answer (score 4):

Ваш поток был скушан GC (сборщиком мусора) до его завершения. Это может произойти в любой момент после завершения функции `__init__`. От этого как-раз разные числа и получаются. Чтоб этого не произошло нужно присвоить его в переменную, которая будет доступна на время выполнения.

```
self.thread = Thread(target=self.get_total_count).start()
```

Перед тем как работать total_count можно дождаться выполнения треда через

```
self.thread.join()
```

без join у вас будет промежуточный результат, но он будет если тред успел завршиться.

Comment: А прямо вот в питоне GC прямо такой жадный и всё время бегает и собирает лишнюю память без особой необходимости? )

Comment: @CrazyElf он больше внезапный чем жадный) работает через подсчет ссылок. Ссылок на тред не будет после инита

Comment: Как он работает я в курсе. Но чтобы он прям так часто - не успел тред запустить, как уже - это что-то сомнительно. Обычно GC зовут когда доступной памяти становится меньше определённого порога. Часто звать GC - путь к тормозам.

Comment: так там http и суп - довольно долго может работать